# Why wasn't this post "spam"?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I got a note in my flags today that my recent flag was declined, *"declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it "*, on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60127214/2029983). For those without 10K rep:

[image]

The spam flag's description is:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the author's affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

I'm just wondering, what about that answer doesn't promote a service, or where does it disclose their affiliation? Is my understanding of what is spam flawed?

I notice that the answer has since been deleted, but I don't know if that was by someone else (a different moderator), or for different reasons. If I used the wrong flag, what should it have been?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the description of the flag should be tweaked. The intent (in so far as we can read the mind of whoever articulated that description) is to disallow *unsolicited* promotions.

If a product or service solves exactly the problem in the question, we should be allowed and encouraged to link to that product or service.

If it is *our own* product or service, or we have a relationship with its provider (employee, spouse, whatever) we absolutely must disclose our affiliation with it.

(Obviously, questions *asking* for recommendations are explicitly disallowed for other reasons; but sometimes, the simplest solution to a programming problem is an existing offering.)

Comment: Ok, but what if the "solicitation" has an ulterior motive, too? The Q/A in this case looks a bit like _Q: "Hey, does someone know a really good fresh beverage?" - A: "Yes, of course, you should try Poopsie Cola! Don't worry, you get a free sample if you like!"_

Comment: Such schemes are not unheard of, and sometimes I personally flag as spam simply based on intuition, but without evidence to support foul play, such as repeats on other sites or over time, I don't think a moderator would be inclined to accept the flag, nor should they. Your example is clearly more promotional than we normally accept here, but if nothing else is wrong, that can be fixed with an edit.

Comment: @Ctx see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8323/astroturfing-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 3):

That answer doesn't appear to be spam.

There is a difference between a recommendation and advertising.

You can't say that the user is not disclosing their affiliation unless you believe there is an undisclosed affiliation. Do you believe there is? What are your grounds to believe so?

*"A link to a product or service"* does not automatically constitute spam. The important part is that you need to believe there is:

- an undisclosed affiliation
- or that there is a disclosed affiliation but that the post
  is solely made to promote a thing
- or that there is an excess of promotion going on with that particular user, even if disclosed (e.g. they mainly post to promote their thing)

If you have no reason to believe any of these apply, and it's simply a link to a product or service (or anything else); that's not spam. That's just link-only answer (if the answer contains no useful information but the link(s)).

If you **do not have some evidence** about a post being spam, do not resort to the nuclear option when a lesser flag would be equally effective.

Remember that a post deleted as spam will punish the user with -100 reputation, so it's not an option to be used lightly.

Comment: *"It doesn't appear to be SPAM."* Why? All the answer did was promote a product/service.

Comment: But the spam flag specifically calls out that the answer *"**does not** disclose the author's affiliation."*

Comment: I don't disagree that it isn't low-quality as well. But my opinion is that's also spam, and hence why I'm asking why the flag was declined. I don't see how this answer actually answers that question, as it doesn't tell me what about the question doesn't fit the SPAM description.

Comment: You've updated the answer since I made that comment; so it does more address what I'm asking. Effectively you're now saying my understanding of the flag is flawed; that wasn't what the answer you made said before. So you're saying unless someone has evidence of affiliation it isn't spam? I personally disagree with that notion.

Comment: _"All the answer did was promote a product/service"_ And that was exactly what the question asks for, @Larnu

Comment: The fact that asking for tool recommendations is off topic for SO is a completely different point @BillTür ;)

Comment: Once there is some rep on an account and/or "normal" activity you would indeed go easy with the spam flag. Looks like the account has > 50 rep and some badges  @Larnu  so unless they posted that same link a third time you assume good faith. It is not only the rep penalty but also an IP ban which is rather harsh if you get it wrong.

Comment: Hormel actually specifically request that we abstain from using the product stylization when discussing unsolicited internet promotions. Personally I could care less what the company thinks, but it's definitely not an argument in favor of doing the opposite. Personally, I simply regard all caps as an eyesore.

Comment: @Larnu "does not disclose the author's affiliation" means that someone recommending something they made (or are affiliated with) without saying they made it, _is_ spam. If the author has no affiliation, that doesn't fit the criteria - a recommendation is not spam. It may be "not an answer" and flaggable as such, but not spam.

Comment: That does make it very difficult to actually determine if anything is spam though, @ArtOfCode , as without knowledge of the real person, you have no way of knowing that. I personally therefore feel that the comment for spam isn't great, as it's too open to interpretation.

Comment: @Larnu if the name of the user seems to coincides with the software (tool: `Widgetor`, user: `Widget0r`) or the maker of the software (`Widgetor` by `ACME Corp`, user `ACME`). Or check their profile - if it states explicitly "I made `Widgetor`" or "I work at `ACME`" or perhaps a link to the product. This should few moments to check. You don't really need to go deeper but you can - check the Widgetor page and list of authors, verify if the username doesn't exist there. If none of these matches, it's likely not spam...just a link-only answer.

Comment: @Larnu I have 1395 helpful spam flags on SO, with 5 declined. I'm pretty sure I didn't know any of the spammers.

Comment: I didn't you you don't, @rene . The problem, however, (from my perspective) appears to be the wording of the comment about what "spam" is; and why I've marked the other answer the solution. It seems that my interpretation of the intent was incorrect, but that was due to it's ambiguity.

Comment: If it wasn't spam, why did a moderator, delete the answer?  It sure looks like spam to me.  I mean the link is a referral link.

Comment: @SecurityHound It could have been deleted as being "link only". It doesn't appear that the answer was deleted as spam. Spam/Rude deleted posts are partially redacted, and >10k users need to click an additional link to be able to see their contents. That's not the case here.

Comment: That link just has Google's UTMs in it, @SecurityHound, it doesn't look like a link that actually gets someone paid. Looks like the author just googled the question and posted a link. It's not an answer (and was deleted) because it doesn't answer the question (if the link breaks, what use is the answer? How does it apply? etc), but it does seem to be an attempt at answering rather than link planting.